# fetch mysql result flat list react-native

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, react-native

i'm currently trying to create a search item function in react-native,the data is stored in MySql database, this is what i already made

**SearchArticle.js (fetch parts)**

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataPeople:[],
      isLoading: true,
      TextInput_ItemCode: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._fetchItem()
  }

  _fetchItem = () => {
    fetch("http://192.168.181.59/article/SearchArticleList.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        itemcode: this.state.TextInput_ItemCode,
      })
    })
      .then((response)=>response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=>{
          console.log(responseJson);
          this.setState({
          isLoading:false,
          dataPeople:responseJson.item
          });
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
          console.error(error)
        })
  };

  _itemCoponent=({item})=>{
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: 'row',marginLeft: 10,}} >
              <View style={{flex:2,height:50}}>
                <Text style={{padding:1}} >{item.id} - {item.itemcode}</Text>
                <Text style={{ padding: 1 }}>{item.description}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
        ) 
    }

    _separatorComponent=()=>{
        return(
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'grey',height:0.5}}></View>
        )
    }
```

**SearchArticle.js (render parts)**

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, textAlign: "center", marginBottom: 7 }}>
          {" "}
          Search Article{" "}
        </Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Itemcode"
          onChangeText={TextInputValue =>
            this.setState({ TextInput_ItemCode: TextInputValue })
          }
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          keyboardType='numeric'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.4}
          style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
          onPress={this._fetchItem}
        >
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}>
            {" "}
            SEARCH{" "}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <FlatList 
                data={this.state.dataPeople}
                renderItem={this._itemCoponent}
                keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this._separatorComponent}
        /> 

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the **SearchArticleList.php** which provide the JSON to be rendered in FlatList

```js
<?php
include 'koneksi-lkl.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$itemcode = $obj['itemcode'];
$Sql_Query = "SELECT id,itemcode,description FROM article where itemcode='$itemcode' limit 1 ";

$result = $con->query($Sql_Query);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    while($row['item'][]= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $item = $row;
    $json = json_encode($item);
    }
} else {
$MSG = 'No Results Found.' ;
$json = json_encode($MSG);
 }
echo $json;
$con->close();
?>
```

and this is the JSON output

```html
{
    "item":[
    {
        "id":"25843",
        "itemcode":"4974305159472",
        "description":"WATER PITCHER DGB-17C CA ZJ"
    }
    ]
}
```

code above meant to fetching the JSON data from server and then rendered into FlatList but somehow the FlatList not showing the result as it should be, after i hit the Search button the FlatList didn't load anything, but when i check in the console, the JSON data is fetched as it should be.

where is my code probably wrong ? or is there any other way to do this which more efficient and more "clean" ?

thanks in advance

Comment: If the console.log(responseJson) is printing as expected, it's likely the rendering phase that is the issue. However, can you show the code for `this._itemCoponent`. Also probably worth noting that component was misspelt here.

Comment: did you meant this function ,
`code`
_itemCoponent=({item})=>{
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: 'row',marginLeft: 10,}} >
              <View style={{flex:2,height:50}}>
                <Text style={{padding:1}} >{item.id} - {item.itemcode}</Text>
                <Text style={{ padding: 1 }}>{item.description}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
        ) 
    }
`code`
no, it's not mispelt it's just intentional

Comment: I've put your code (with static JSON data and no search form/button trigger) into this and it works. The FlatList is updated: https://snack.expo.io/ryIA4kFCB